# Android: How to pass list of object into ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have class

```
public class User
{
   UUID id;
   String name;
}
```

I want to pass into ListView this: List and display only "name".
But when item in list view will be selected I want to know "id" of the selected item.

Comment: Please clarify how you want the id of the selected item to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store the object into an arraylist say like

```
Arraylist<User> al = new ArrayList<User>();
```

then add the objects to the arraylist using

```
 User user = new User(); 
 user.id = somevalue;
 user.name = someNameValue;
 al.add(user);
```

Next in the onitemclick() get the item clicked and next display it using the arraylist item

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

Toast.makeText(this, "item clicked is " + arg2+al.get(arg2).id+"  "al.get(arg2).name,     
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
 .show();
}
}
```

Comment: How to pass this ArrayList into ListView?

Comment: you can use listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
Where adapter can be adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);
Have a look at http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-list-view-sample.html or http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/07/custom-list-view.html they may be helpful

Comment: al - is the array with our objects?

Comment: Yes al is the array with my objects

Answer (score 4):

First I would make a class that contains both pieces of information.

```
public class MyItem {

public final String name;
public final String id;

public MyItem(String name, String id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
 }

}
```

Then make a custom Adapter that can support this class.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyItem> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<MyItem> items;
private LayoutInflater vi;

public EntryAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<MyItem> items) {
    super(context,0, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    final Item i = items.get(position);
    if (i != null) {
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null); //custom xml for desired view
            //do what ever you need to

    }
    return v;
     }

     }
```

Populate an Array of MyItem's, then crete your custom Adapter using the Array.

```
items = new ArrayList<MyItem>(); // then populate it
myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, items);
```

Now set up the ListView and use OnItemClickListener

```
myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View view, int position,
                long id) 
        {
                ((MyItem)myAdapter.getItem(position)).id); //this line gets you the id of the clicked item

        }
    });
```

Comment: Why do we need: UserSearchItem method?

Comment: Whoops, meant to be a constructor, let me fix.